# Minimize travel distance of n people to n locations

Tags: algorithms, game-development, artificial-intelligence

The problem:

Given the coordinates of N people on a regular 2-dimensional plane and N target points-of-interest (POI) on the same plane, determine the set of pairs of people and POIs that minimize the sum of straight-line distances between the locations in each pair.  No two people can go to the same POI, and all POIs must be covered.

In other words, if I have 5 trucks that need to go to 5 locations and trucks are interchangeable, where do I send the trucks so that the least amount of fuel is used (assuming fuel use is proportional to distance traveled)?

Discussion:

Brute force would take N factorial.  Is there a better way?  This would seem to be a pretty common operations research problem, but my google-fu is insufficient.

Comment: This sounds like the travelling salesman problem.
Edit: See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/123189/algorithm-for-an-exact-solution-to-the-travelling-purchaser-problem

Comment: This is known as the *assignment problem*: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem - Wikipedia lists some algorithms to solve it in polynomial time.

Comment: You're right!  More specifically, it is exactly the [transportation problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transportation_theory_%28mathematics%29).

Comment: So is that the answer? Sounds a bit like homework to me.

Answer (score 1):

Copying the comments to get the problem out of the unanswered problems queue, and making it community wiki.

This sounds like the travelling salesman problem. See [Algorithm for an exact solution to the Travelling Purchaser Problem](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/123189/algorithm-for-an-exact-solution-to-the-travelling-purchaser-problem)

This is known as the assignment problem: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem - Wikipedia lists some algorithms to solve it in polynomial time.

You're right! More specifically, it is exactly the transportation problem.